# Scala Slick 3: Count Rows and get row

Tags: sql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I cannot figure out how to count with Slick (3).

```
val posts = for {
  p <- Posts.query if p.receiver === userId
  comments <- Comments.query if comments.postId === p.id
  author <- Users.query if p.author === author.id
  receiver <- Users.query if p.receiver === receiver.id
} yield (p, comments, author, receiver)
```

With the following relationships

```
Posts : Author : Receiver : Comments
1 : 1 : 1 : N
```

The result should be:

```
Future[Seq[(Post, User, User, Int)]]
```

with the `int` being the count of comments `grouped by Posts`

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your result by post, author and receiver and the map to aggregate the comments by just counting them.

```
val posts = (for {
  p <- Posts.query if p.receiver === userId
  comment <- Comments.query if comments.postId === p.id
  author <- Users.query if p.author === author.id
  receiver <- Users.query if p.receiver === receiver.id
} yield (p, comment, author, receiver)) //So far thats your current query
  .groupBy({ //Group by post, author and receiver
      case (post, comment, author, receiver) =>
          (post, author, receiver)
  })
  .map({ //Aggregate your comments (second argument in tuple) and count them
      case ((post, author, receiver), list) => { 
          (post, author, receiver, list.map(_._2).count))
      }
  })
```

On mobile currently so this probably won't compile, but you should get the idea.